# Xcode source code editor freezes, does not scroll any more

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode-6.2

I have a small OS X Objective C project that I am working on for about two weeks now. Yesterday Xcode started to stop scrolling and updating the editor area for the source files. I start Xcode and open the project, I can click on my .m and .h files and scroll around for a while (half a minute or less), then the cursor vanishes, the last file stays on the screen even when I click on other files in the project navigator. No more editing or scrolling. When I select the project file in the navigator, the editor area changes partly to the usual project settings view, but I can't edit anything. Activity Monitor does not show any suspicious behavior of Xcode.

What I did yesterday: I imported and exported localizations several times, changed my app icon, did some minor code changes.

I am using Xcode 6.2 on OS X 10.10.2. Other projects do not cause this problem.

Any ideas where to look at before I start moving everything to a new project?

Comment: bugreport.apple.com and tell them your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be Dropbox-related: I moved the project folder from my Dropbox folder to another folder and everything works fine now. I am not sure if it was a temporary network-related problem or a problem with my Dropbox account, but now it is gone.

This was the only project I actually worked on while it was in a Dropbox folder.